# React setState not setting state of input field

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I am using Gatsby. This is my code:

```
import React from "react"

class ContactCard extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { form: { name: "test" }, message: ""};
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    }
    handleSubmit = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
    };

    handleChange = e => {
        console.log("handleChange: " + e.target.name + " = " + e.target.value);
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value, message: "event value: " + e.target.value });
        /*
        I also tried the following:
        this.setState({ name: e.target.value, message: "event value: " + e.target.value });
        */
    }

    render() {
        const { form: { name }, message } = this.state;
        return (
            <>
                <p>{message} name: {name} </p>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        value={name}
                        name="name"
                        onChange={this.handleChange}
                    />
                </form>
            </>
        );
    }
}
export default ContactCard
```

When I type in the input box I see the following in the console log:

> handleChange: name = testg

And the P tag changes to have the following text:

> event value: testg name: test

The input box's value does not change it remains the same no matter what I do. As commented in my code, I also tried to setState on name directly instead of using the event name, that did not work. I also tried the following:

```
handleChange = e => {
    console.log("handleChange: " + e.target.name + " = " + e.target.value);
    var newState = { [e.target.name]: e.target.value, message: "event value: " + e.target.value };
    this.setState(newState);
}
```

This results in the same behavior. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

You are incorrectly setting state. Your state shape has `name` as a property of `state.form`, so the `setState` needs to match this shape.

## Solution

Nest `[e.target.name]: e.target.value` in the `form` object. Ensure you shallow copy any existing form state as well. The React `setState` will shallow merge the root object, but it won't do a deep merge of nested state updates.

Since react state updates are asynchronous and (*currently in react 16.x*) react synthetic events are typically quickly nullified and returned to the event pool, you may also want to save the event `name` and `value` properties *before* enqueueing the state update.

```
handleChange = (e) => {
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  this.setState((prevState) => ({
    form: {
      ...prevState.form,
      [name]: value
    },
    message: "event value: " + value
  }));
};
```

[image: Edit react-setstate-not-setting-state-of-input-field]

Answer (score 0):

So you are updating the new state incorrectly.
You should be nesting *name* within the *form* property.

Sending from a mobile device, Pardon my formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try binding the value of input to `this.state.form.name` instead like so:

```js
<input
 type="text"
 value={this.state.form.name}
 name="name"
 onChange={this.handleChange}
/>
```